# alternativas Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Gostaria de saber quais sao as alternativas para substituir um iframe.

Tenho este código:

```
<iframe src="noticia.html" width="550" height="400" 
scrolling="auto" style="position: absolute; left: 2%; top: 38%;"> 

</iframe>
```

Comment: O que você precisa fazer?

Comment: encontrar uma forma de mostrar um iframe em todos os Browsers incluindo o IE8. 
so quero mostrar aquela página que tambem fui eu que criei

Answer (score 1):

**Opção 1**

```
   <embed src="noticia.html" width=100 height=100 />
```

Funciona, mas de acordo com W3C é para conteúdo interativo ou mídia

**Opção 2**
Através do XMLHttpRequest e postar o conteúdo em uma div.

```
function loadPage(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    //IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("ID_do_elemento").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","WEBPAGE YOU WANT TO LOAD",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar a função Load do Jquery para incluir um arquivo html dentro da tua página!
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Seria interresante mostrar o funcionamento da função para deixar sua resposta mais completa